# Google Sheets Filter - Pull through rows onto another tab based on date (e.g. Aug 2019)

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of invoices on tab 'Main' where each has a specific date on which they were created e.g. 15/09/2019.

I have subsequent tabs 'Sept 2019', 'Aug 2019' and so on. At the moment I am filtering the 'Main' tab with the condition e.g. text contains '09/2019' to get a list of all the invoices created in Sept 2019, and then manually copying them to the corresponding ' Sept 2019' tab.

Is there a filter I can set up on the monthly tabs so they automatically pull through a copy of the entire row if they fulfill the date criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, in sheet `Sept 2019` you can paste this fx:

```
=FILTER(Main!A:D, MONTH(Main!A:A)=9, YEAR(Main!A:A)=2019)
```

assuming dates are in Column A in Main sheet

Comment: Thank you so much!! The formula needing a bit of tweaking (mainly due to my parameters being slightly different) but you got me there. That's been bothering me for ages!! 

=FILTER('MAIN SHEET'!B:H, MONTH('MAIN SHEET'!B:B)=9, YEAR('MAIN SHEET'!B:B)=2019)